# Subsample a XY meshgrid matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-indexing

I have a matrix of XYZ data, X and Y are in a regular "meshgrid format", I need to reduce the number of points by some factor. sample:

```
stepXY = 1;
X = 1:stepXY:100;
Y = 1:stepXY:80;

[Xm,Ym] = meshgrid(X,Y);

XYZ = [Xm(:) Ym(:)]';
XYZ(3,:) = 7;
```

How to get a XYZ2 = XYZ as a step of 10 (in XY) instead of 1? I can't just get an element after each 10 steps becouse this you result in something like:

```
1 1  7
1 10 7
.
.
.
2 1 7 <==== look, X should be 10 here.
```

Comment: Why not just do another meshgrid with stepXY = 10?

Comment: Because the data is already formed and I need to subsample it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create new vectors of `X` and `Y` values with your new step size, then use [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to find indices where your old values are members of your new sets. For example, if you want your new step size in both the x and y directions to be 10, you would do this:

```
newStep = 10;
newX = 1:newStep:100;
newY = 1:newStep:80;
index = ismember(XYZ(1, :), newX) & ismember(XYZ(2, :), newY);
XYZ2 = XYZ(:, index);

XYZ2 =

  Columns 1 through 24

     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1    11    11    11    11    11    ...
     1    11    21    31    41    51    61    71     1    11    21    31    41    ...
     7     7     7     7     7     7     7     7     7     7     7     7     7    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:

```
Zm = X*0+7;  %or whatever your data is
XYZ = cat(3,Xm,Ym,Zm);
XYZ_subsample = XYZ(1:10:end,1:10:end,:);
```